# Dynamic Questionnaire Logic in React: Checkbox Limits, Chart Options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project, I find myself facing a situation where I need to create questions and store them in a database. Each question should come with a checkbox, and when clicked, it should reveal a dropdown with various graph options such as bar, pie, and area.

The components for creating these elements are in place, but I need to implement specific logic:

1. I am limited to checking only three checkboxes for a maximum of three questions. If there are ten questions, I can only check three of them, and the remaining seven should be disabled until the checked ones are unchecked.
2. For the first question, users can see all three chart options in the dropdown (bar, pie, area). If the user selects the bar chart, subsequent questions should not display the bar option in the dropdown.
3. Additionally, when a user refreshes the page, all previously saved questions, along with their checkboxes and selected dropdown options, should be displayed.

Could someone please assist me in developing the logic to handle this scenario?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question